# Integrate Sound Cloud with Angular 8

Tags: angular, html5-audio, soundcloud, angular8

I have music in my Sound Cloud account and I want to integrate it into my application in Angular 8. Is there any way to take a URL like this https://soundcloud.com/sonus-fx/paf-custom- bridge-drive-x2 and integrated to my application?

I know that the sound cloud has an option to share and that gives you a . But the problem with that is that I have to do it with all the links of my music. I planned to have a  and using interpolation to inject a url like this https://soundcloud.com/sonus-fx/paf-custom- bridge-drive-x2.

Or is there another place where I can upload my music and be able to integrate it more easily? Because the Sound Cloud Api needs Premium.

I hope I explained well.

If I use this, dosen't look good.

`<iframe width = "100%" height = "300" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "no" allow = "autoplay" src = "https://soundcloud.com/sonus-fx/paf-custom- bridge-drive -x2 "> </iframe>`

Comment: The src of your iframe returns 404 when pasted in a browser tab, how is it supposed to work in an iframe?

Comment: Yes, it works badly because I copied another code that I didn't have to copy.

This was what i meant...

``<iframe width = "100%" height = "300" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "no" allow = "autoplay" src = "https://soundcloud.com/sonus-fx/paf-custom- bridge-drive -x2 "> </iframe>``

Anyway, that code was an example.

Comment: Use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mintplayer/ng-soundcloud-player)